# Date comparision in javascript + jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script piece in an javascript function to validate some fields in my form

```
var situacao = $("select[name='situacaoCRC']").val();
var dta_emissao = $("input[name='dtaEmissao']").val();
var dta_validade = $("input[name='dtaValidade']").val();

if (situacao == -1) {
    alert('Selecione um estado para o CRC.');
return false;
}

if (dta_emissao === undefined || dta_emissao === "") {
    alert('Data de emissão do CRC inválida.');
return false;
}

if (dta_validade === undefined || dta_validade === "") {
alert('Data de validade do CRC inválida.');
return false;
}

if (dta_validade <= dta_emissao) {
    alert('A data de validade do CRC deve ser posterior à data de emissão.');
return false;
}
```

The fields dta_validade and dta_emissao are both dates in the format DD/MM/YYYY

When i put in this fields, let's say, dta_validade = 01/12/2011 and dta_emissao = 01/01/2012 and, with this data, i get the alert in the 4th IF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your last last *if* to:

```
if (parseDate(dta_validade) <= parseDate(dta_emissao)) {
    alert('A data de validade do CRC deve ser posterior à data de emissão.');
    return false;
}
```

Then you can add:

```
function parseDate(s) {
    var a = s.split('/');
    return new Date(parseInt(a[2]), parseInt(a[1])-1, parseInt(a[0])); // month is zero-based
}
```

Don't forget error handling.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create 2 date objects, before you can compare them. You can find some information about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp

```
var test_date1;
test_date = new Date(2011, 11, 1); //Year, Month (zero based), Day
```

(In this case you need to parse the values of the year, month and day yourself)

You can also use Datejs to make things easier for you: http://www.datejs.com

Or, seeing as you're already using jQuery, use the jQuery UI Datepicker: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

```
$.datepicker.formatDate( format, date, settings ) 
// Format a date into a string value with a specified format.
$.datepicker.parseDate( format, value, settings ) 
// Extract a date from a string value with a specified format.
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit Cros, I always forget that Month is indeed zero based (from 0 [January] to 11 [December]).